# is android lifecycle methods order garanted?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I know this place is full of questions about the lifecycle of androids components.

I would like to know if the order of lifecycle events IN DIFFERENT ACTIVITIES can be garanted.

With an example is easier to understand. Lets say A and B are activies, let's suppose i do:

```
a.finish();
a.startActivity(new Intent(a,B.class));
```

Does Android scheculer garantee that `A.onStop()`, `A.onDestroy()` will be called before `B.onCreate()`, `B.onStart()`?

I know those methods are not called imediatally after the invoke of finish(); nor startActivity();, but i want to know about the order... is it possible to assure the order those methods will be called?

Comment: IMHO, if you have two activities that are that closely coupled, they should not be separate activities. Use one activity and two fragments, for example.

Comment: that would be a good idea but i'm in a point of the project that this change would cost me a lot to rebuild, i should've asked this months ago. If i do get a negative answer is easier to me change the onStart()/onStop() logic than rebuild whole activity

Answer (score 1):

There is no promise of the ordering of calls between two activities.  Particularly the onDestroy call.  The start/stop/pause/resume have some implicit ordering based on their meaning (pause means you're no longer the foreground activity, stop means you're completely off screen, so it makes no sense for stop to be called before B's onStart, as it may otherwise be incorrect).  But onDestroy can definitely be delayed until convenient for the system, there's no hard ordering to it other than after A's onStop.